# HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: TypeError: Application() takes no arguments

Tags: python, appium, bdd, gherkin

I am trying to automate a desktop application on Windows 10 with the following stack: Python + `Appium` + `WinAppDriver`. 
I use the Gherkin language and Page Object Pattern.

After running the feature file, I have a failing result with the error HOOK-ERROR in `before_scenario: TypeError: Application() takes no arguments`

I do not have any idea how to solve it. I would be very grateful for the tips.

My project structure:

application.py

```
from page.login_page import AdminLoginPage

class Application:

      def __int__(self, driver):
          self.admin_login_page = AdminLoginPage(driver)
```

environment.py

```
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from app.application import Application


def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    desired_capabilities = {
        "platform": "Windows",
        "platformVersion": "10",
        "app": "C:\Program Files (x86)\path\path\application.exe"
    }

    context.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
    context.driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    context.app = Application(context.driver)


def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.driver.quit()
```

The AdminLoginPage class inherits from the BasePage class.
In BasePage class I described all action which user can perform on element e.g click, input, scroll

login_page.py

```
from page.base_page import BasePage


class AdminLoginPage(BasePage):
    user_name = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'TextBox'),
    password = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'PasswordBox'),
    login_button = (By.NAME, 'Log In')

    def __int__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)

    def enter_user_name(self, user_name):
        self.input_element(self.user_name, user_name)

    def enter_password(self, pwd):
        self.input_element(self.password, pwd)

    def click_login(self):
        self.click_element_if_possible(self.login_button)
```

feature file

```
Feature: Login as a Admin

  Scenario: Login as a Admin
    When I enter username "UserName1"
    And I enter password "Test1"
    And I click Login button
```

steps.py

```
from behave import *


@step('I enter username "{user_name}"')
def enter_username(context, user_name):
    context.app.admin_login_page.enter_user_name(user_name)


@step('I enter password "{pwd}"')
def enter_pwd(context, pwd):
    context.app.admin_login_page.enter_password(pwd)


@step('I click Login button')
def click_login_btn(context):
    context.app.admin_login_page.click_login()
```

Project folders:

[image: project structure in Pycharm]

Answer (score 1):

Typo in application.py

should be

```
def __init__(self, driver):
```

instead of

```
def __int__(self, driver):
```